# error after adding grails-datastore-rest-client plug-in

Tags: rest, grails, rest-client

Using grails version :4.0.0.RC2
      groovy version :2.5.6

```
dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.0.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC6"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates"
    compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:6.1.12.RELEASE"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:angular"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.16"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
}

After adding 
compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:6.1.12.RELEASE" plug in getting below error

ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : NoSuchMethodError occurred when processing request: [GET] /ExecSummary/dashboard
grails.core.GrailsDomainClass.getIdentifier()Lgrails/core/GrailsDomainClassProperty;. Stacktrace follows:
```

caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: grails.core.GrailsDomainClass.getIdentifier()Lgrails/core/GrailsDomainClassProperty;

My requirement to consume external REST services. These must be some issue with the conflicted plug-in, any suggestions.

Should I move to any other Grails version. or any other changes in terms of plugins.

Comment: You should at least use the latest version of Grails 4 (4.0.0) - not a release candidate.

Comment: Now we are using Grails 4.0.0, previous Error gone. Now getting another error.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "<URL>": connect timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744)  
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)

Comment: Seems you cant connect to whatever you're API your calling - open another issue with the code if you're still having issues.